# GradleConnection Exception: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using specified Gradle distribution

Tags: gradle, android-studio

When I fired up Android Studio and tried to compile and existing project (minSDK 11 and targetSDK 19). It failed with GradleConnnectionException Error. I tried to remove .grade in project direction and removed gradle-19-all in the ~/.gradle's dist directory and tried to rebuild the project, but it did not help.

[image: Before deleting gradle-19-all]

[image: After Deleting]

What does this error message indicate? Any suggestions as how can I fix this?

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: Is this Android Studio 0.4.0? Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @ScottBarta - This is 0.3.2 and i have posted my build.gradle Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Mac OS X El Capitan and it turned out to be a conflicting library installed by AusKey.

A work around is to move /Library/Java/Extensions/slf4j*.jar files to another directory when not using AusKey.

More details here http://tumblr.twicetwice.net/post/65213314698/cant-create-a-new-project-with-android-studio-on

Comment: Wow, I don't know how long it would have taken me to figure this out without this!

Answer (score 1):

The 0.7 plugin isn't compatible with Android Studio 0.3.2, nor is Gradle 1.9. You can either use the 0.6 plugin with Gradle 1.8, or upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.0.